# Repair python installation

Tags: python

I've probably mess up my python installation.
For using ssl with python I've try to install paramiko:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install paramiko
```

I tought with `sudo pip install paramiko`, I install it correctly for the whole system. On a ubuntu 16.4 machine, this was successfully, but perhaps, on a raspberry it was not a good idea? The install fails and I additionally install

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

After that, I installed separately `sudo pip install cryptography`

It seems, that this was successfully, but now I got in many cases this error

```
pip --version
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version`

How can I fix this?

Python 2.7.9/ Raspbian GNU/Linux 8

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

After uninstall pip with

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

and install the newest version without apt

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

and reinstalling paramiko, it seems all OK.